# Proxy to Secure IMAP server

Tags: ssl, proxy, imap

I am trying to connect a client to a secure (SSL/TLS) IMAP server. The client code cannot handle SSL/TLS correctly, so I am trying to see if a proxy server can be used in the middle. I was thinking something like the following:

```
IMAP Client <------- Plain Text Requests -------> Proxy <------- SSL/TLS Requests -------> SSL/TLS protected IMAP server.
```

I think this is possible but I am curious on what products can be used for the proxy? And, is this a normal deployment option?

Thanks much,

Ash

Comment: No, that isn't normal. It was normal in the nineties.

Comment: You are way better off figuring out your client code SSL/TLS problems rather than trying to offload them.

Answer (score 3):

Use [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/). With it you can do direct TLS (i.e. imaps, port 993) and also TLS upgrade of a plain IMAP connection (port 143) using the STARTTLS command. See the [documentation](https://www.stunnel.org/static/stunnel.html) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

This is insane. An obvious fix is to find out why your client software cannot handle TLS. Deploying proxies or standalone tunnels makes little sense.

Seriously, if your "client" cannot even establish a TLS connection, it's either severely misconfigured, has damaged installation, or so bad that it won't reliably work even after you deploy this bandaid.